# unityで使えるのはasset storeにあるものだけですか?

Tags: unity3d

unityで部屋を作りたいのですが、
asset storeに思うようなものがありません。

asset store以外で手に入れた3Dデータでも取り込むことができるのでしょうか。

選択してとしてどのようなものがあるのがあるのか教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2):

> http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/Manual/HOWTO-importObject.html

上記URL参照です。
すべてそこに答えがあります。

基本そういったことは公式ドキュメントにきちんと説明がなされているので、
質問する前にちゃんと読むように心がけることが大切です。